# Volume/Power button metal ring

Tags: iphone, hardware

Today I've started my custom iPhone 6s 128GB build out of new parts. Only the motherboard was used. I came to the part where I had to screw the bracket for holding the power button in place. When screwing the bracket in I realised a very important part of the button. A good working button requires the power button itself, metal spacer and a metal ring what goes into the button. The work of the metal ring is for getting the button pushed back when clicked in.

The problem now is I forgot to order the metal rings for my upper buttons.. I am searching everywhere online, but cannot find anything at all. Does anyone know where I can get those metal rings (NOT METAL SPACERS!!).

Picture:
http://www.t-shirtlicious.com/3574-18661-thickbox/apple-iphone-6-plus-silver-power-volume-button-with-spacer-original-new.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [set of buttons](https://www.unionrepair.com/replacement-for-iphone-6s-side-buttons-set-silver.html), with the "ring" you requested for less than a dollar from UnionRepair, among many other suppliers. I linked the silver ones but they have all the colours. Also note that you will also need to order the [1mm metal contacts](https://www.unionrepair.com/replacement-for-iphone-6-6p-6s-6sp-universal-power-button-contact-1mm.html) in order for the button to properly actuate the switch on the flex.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I said no metal spacers. I am talking about the metal thing what goes inside the button from the left and right side. I have an image: http://www.t-shirtlicious.com/3574-18661-thickbox/apple-iphone-6-plus-silver-power-volume-button-with-spacer-original-new.jpg

Comment: That ring comes with the buttons, at least it should. I've updated the answer with a proper link. The picture would have helped when you asked the question.